# How to implement ReportViewer scroll zoom?

Tags: wpf, scroll, zooming, reportviewer

I am designing a report using ReportViewer and WPF. Now I want to implement the Ctrl+scroll zoom functionality (I thought it should be the behavior by default like DocumentViewer but it seems not). I can't find any reference to that. Can anyone give me some hints?